# How do i join a list made of variables into a string (python[3.6.2])

Tags: python

there is too much code to put here so i'll just show where the problem is happening:

```
date = [day,month,year,time]
entrylist = [name,guess,date,email,phone]
entry = ''.join(entrylist)
print(entry)
```

Comment: You have list of list, you need for inside: `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found` error message says all

Comment: probably just `entry = ''.join(str(e) for e in entrylist)` will work... but that's hard to tell without knowing what your variables are... please provide
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What "problem is happening"? The question can't really be answered without that information.

Comment: this is the error: entry = ''.join(entrylist)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Comment: Your code raises `TypeError` in my interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

With ''.join(list) it should work.

```
>>> entrylist = ['name','guess','date','email','phone']
>>> entry = ''.join(entrylist)
>>> print(entry)
nameguessdateemailphone
>>> entry = ' '.join(entrylist)
>>> print(entry)
name guess date email phone
>>>
```

If list of lists needs to be joined then use below format

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, "sekar"],[3, "hello", "stack"],["overflow" ,4, "hi"]]
>>> ''.join(str(r) for v in a for r in v)
'12sekar3hellostackoverflow4hi'
>>> ' '.join(str(r) for v in a for r in v)
'1 2 sekar 3 hello stack overflow 4 hi'
>>>
```

and if you want to combine the list of list with the variables then see below

```
>>> a = ['stack']
>>> b = ['over']
>>> c = ['flow']
>>> finallist = a + b + c
>>> ''.join(finallist)
'stackoverflow'
```

if your list has numeric values then you will have to convert those to string before trying to concatenate, else exception will be thrown like below.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, "sekar"]
>>> b = [3, "hello", "stack"]
>>> c = ["overflow" ,4, "hi"]
>>> finallist = a + b + c
>>> " ".join(x for x in finallist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
>>> " ".join(str(x) for x in finallist)
'1 2 sekar 3 hello stack overflow 4 hi'
>>>
```